# Is there a way to arrange the columns in the grid when the Sales order list page is loaded?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm stuck with an issue in the sales order Grid in Dynamics AX 2012 R2. Somehow after adding new columns to the grid via personalization, the newly added columns always shifts to the left side after closing/opening the sales order list page.

Is there any Grid property that handles the arrangement of the columns?
how can we modify the grid columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sounds like an error, this is not how it works for me.

Consider adding the fields to the `SalesTableListPage` form. The fields are initially (or after reset of user settings) listed in the order in the form grid.

Answer (score 0):

Might look into the list page interaction classes which is responsible for form behavior instead of the AOT on listpages.

more information on the available methods can be found on msdn

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/listpageinteraction.aspx

but it is possible for example that a var/isv customization modifies the form after it is loaded

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).